# while loop to create a list of new class objects

Tags: python, list, loops, object

I am new to python and am using it for some classes, I am trying to figure out how to generate a list of objects. I created a class data type and I want to use a while loop to quickly generate multiple objects of that new data type and store them in a list. the code I have now is down below, I have it set up to (if it worked) make a list (v), start a loop contingent on confirming to loop again, track how many times we have looped with i, create and append a cart_vect (class data type with 3 numeric tags that are prompted for input imported from another set of code) to the list v. loop creating a list of objects and (for now) print the list of objects. I have tried to work it out and find solutions online already but I cant seem to get an answer.

```
v=[]
cont='y'
i=1
while cont=='y':
    v.append(v[-1]+1)
    print('vector',i,':')
    v[-1]=cart_vect(float(input('x:')),float(input('y:')),float(input('z:')))
    i=i+1
    cont=input('another vector? y/n   ')
print(v)
```

Comment: `v.append(v[-1]+1)` won't work. `v` is empty, so there's no `v[-1]`.

Comment: Just use `v.append(cart_vect(...))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.